# How to find the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

More specifically I mean, when we use row operations to find the inverse of matrix, we start by writing $(I\,|\, A)$, where $A$ is a matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.

But when we use column operations to find the inverse of matrix then we start by writing $(A\,|\,I)$.

Why is there this difference and what does it mean? Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean with $A=AI$ or $A=IA$? These equalities are always true, even if $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: alright thanks.

Comment: I just edited your question to try to make your meaning clearer. Please feel free to re-edit or roll back to the original version if I was wrong about what you meant.

Comment: AI meant a matrix A is being multiplied with identity matrix I. what does A|I mean ?